# Making JPanel bigger

Tags: java, swing, tabs, size, jpanel

I am trying to make my JPanel bigger. I have three tabs but when I run the program not all of them show (unless I click the arrows). I just need to know how to make the panel bigger so that I won't have to click the arrows

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;


public class TestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
    frame.setTitle("RBA Test Application");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JButton initialize = new JButton("Initialize");
    JButton connect = new JButton("Connect");
    JButton disconnect = new JButton("Disconnect");
    JButton shutdown = new JButton("Shut Down");
    JButton portsettings = new JButton("Port Settings");


    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.add(initialize);
    buttonPanel.add(connect);
    buttonPanel.add(disconnect);
    buttonPanel.add(shutdown);
    buttonPanel.add(portsettings);
    frame.add(buttonPanel);
    frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    frame.pack();

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    tabbedPane.addTab("LLP", null, null, "Low Level Protocol");
    tabbedPane.addTab("POS",null, null, "Point Of Sale");
    tabbedPane.addTab("Test", null, null, "Test");

    JPanel tabsPanel = new JPanel();
    tabsPanel.add(tabbedPane);
    frame.add(tabsPanel);
    tabsPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 900));
    frame.add(tabsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.pack();



    }






}
```

Comment: i am trying to make my JPanel tabsPanel bigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your tabsPanel a decent layout, i.e., BorderLayout:

```
  JPanel tabsPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); //!!
```

Note, you should not be adding components **twice** to your GUI:

```
  frame.add(buttonPanel);
  frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

And there's no need to call pack() more than once.
Also you should not be calling `setSize(...)` but rather better to override `getPreferredSize()` of a critical component.

Comment: can you tell me how to add buttons to each tab? I need 8 buttons to my LLP tab but I don't know how to do it

Comment: @KendraCheatham: this looks to be a second unrelated question, one that should be asked in a separate thread on this site. If you do this, you'll want to clarify it by explaining exactly what you're trying to do as your comment is not clear.

Comment: Thanks but I figured it out. And thank you for other responses.

Comment: @KendraCheatham: glad you've figured it out, and you're welcome!